# Fastest container or algorithm for unique reusable ids in C++

Tags: c++

I have a need for unique reusable ids. The user can choose his own ids or he can ask for a free one. The API is basically

```
class IdManager {
public:
  int AllocateId();          // Allocates an id
  void FreeId(int id);       // Frees an id so it can be used again
  bool MarkAsUsed(int id);   // Let's the user register an id. 
                             // returns false if the id was already used.
  bool IsUsed(int id);       // Returns true if id is used.
};
```

Assume ids happen to start at 1 and progress, 2, 3, etc.  This is not a requirement, just to help illustrate.

```
IdManager mgr;
mgr.MarkAsUsed(3);
printf ("%d\n", mgr.AllocateId());
printf ("%d\n", mgr.AllocateId());
printf ("%d\n", mgr.AllocateId());
```

Would print

```
1
2
4
```

Because id 3 has already been declared used.

What's the best container / algorithm to both remember which ids are used AND find a free id?

If you want to know the a specific use case, OpenGL's glGenTextures, glBindTexture and glDeleteTextures are equivalent to AllocateId, MarkAsUsed and FreeId

Comment: AllcoatedId() will mark it as used also?

Comment: what's wrong with just letting OpenGL assign and keep track of the ID's for you?

Comment: I'm writing a GL driver. That's why

Yes, AllocateId() will mark it as used.

Comment: Your user name is acceptable. :]

Comment: What's the maximum ID number and the maximum number of IDs allocated at a time? It might make a difference.

Comment: ids and be any number between INT_MIN and INT_MAX inclusive except 0 which is the only invalid ID. There is no maximum number of ids except for running out of memory but I suspect most user programs will use no more than a few thousand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My idea is to use `std::set` and `Boost.interval` so `IdManager` will hold a set of non-overlapping intervals of free IDs. 
`AllocateId()` is very simple and very quick and just returns the left boundary of the first free interval. Other two methods are slightly more difficult because it might be necessary to split an existing interval or to merge two adjacent intervals. However they are also quite fast.

So this is an illustration of the idea of using intervals:

```
IdManager mgr;    // Now there is one interval of free IDs:  [1..MAX_INT]
mgr.MarkAsUsed(3);// Now there are two interval of free IDs: [1..2], [4..MAX_INT]
mgr.AllocateId(); // two intervals:                          [2..2], [4..MAX_INT]
mgr.AllocateId(); // Now there is one interval:              [4..MAX_INT]
mgr.AllocateId(); // Now there is one interval:              [5..MAX_INT]
```

This is code itself:

```
#include <boost/numeric/interval.hpp>
#include <limits>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>


class id_interval 
{
public:
    id_interval(int ll, int uu) : value_(ll,uu)  {}
    bool operator < (const id_interval& ) const;
    int left() const { return value_.lower(); }
    int right() const {  return value_.upper(); }
private:
    boost::numeric::interval<int> value_;
};

class IdManager {
public:
    IdManager();
    int AllocateId();          // Allocates an id
    void FreeId(int id);       // Frees an id so it can be used again
    bool MarkAsUsed(int id);   // Let's the user register an id. 
private: 
    typedef std::set<id_interval> id_intervals_t;
    id_intervals_t free_;
};

IdManager::IdManager()
{
    free_.insert(id_interval(1, std::numeric_limits<int>::max()));
}

int IdManager::AllocateId()
{
    id_interval first = *(free_.begin());
    int free_id = first.left();
    free_.erase(free_.begin());
    if (first.left() + 1 <= first.right()) {
        free_.insert(id_interval(first.left() + 1 , first.right()));
    }
    return free_id;
}

bool IdManager::MarkAsUsed(int id)
{
    id_intervals_t::iterator it = free_.find(id_interval(id,id));
    if (it == free_.end()) {
        return false;
    } else {
        id_interval free_interval = *(it);
        free_.erase (it);
        if (free_interval.left() < id) {
            free_.insert(id_interval(free_interval.left(), id-1));
        }
        if (id +1 <= free_interval.right() ) {
            free_.insert(id_interval(id+1, free_interval.right()));
        }
        return true;
    }
}

void IdManager::FreeId(int id)
{
    id_intervals_t::iterator it = free_.find(id_interval(id,id));
    if (it != free_.end()  && it->left() <= id && it->right() > id) {
        return ;
    }
    it = free_.upper_bound(id_interval(id,id));
    if (it == free_.end()) {
        return ;
    } else {
        id_interval free_interval = *(it);

        if (id + 1 != free_interval.left()) {
            free_.insert(id_interval(id, id));
        } else {
            if (it != free_.begin()) {
                id_intervals_t::iterator it_2 = it;
                --it_2;
                if (it_2->right() + 1 == id ) {
                    id_interval free_interval_2 = *(it_2);
                    free_.erase(it);
                    free_.erase(it_2);
                    free_.insert(
                        id_interval(free_interval_2.left(), 
                                    free_interval.right()));
                } else {
                    free_.erase(it);
                    free_.insert(id_interval(id, free_interval.right()));
                }
            } else {
                    free_.erase(it);
                    free_.insert(id_interval(id, free_interval.right()));
            }
        }
    }
}

bool id_interval::operator < (const id_interval& s) const
{
    return 
      (value_.lower() < s.value_.lower()) && 
      (value_.upper() < s.value_.lower());
}


int main()
{
    IdManager mgr;

    mgr.MarkAsUsed(3);
    printf ("%d\n", mgr.AllocateId());
    printf ("%d\n", mgr.AllocateId());
    printf ("%d\n", mgr.AllocateId());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking as well although I didn't know about boost::numeric::interval.  I'm not quite sure how your < operator finds the correct interval when I call free_.find() but I'm sure I'll figure it out.

Comment: The `insert` in the set could be made more efficient by using the `pos` parameter for a hint in a number of cases. For example, when you decide to erase an interval after allocation, you are going to insert at the exact same place, so keeping the `iterator` that precedes the point of removal + insertion would effectively increase performance since there is no need for a look up at this point.

Comment: Nice work. Allocation is going to be fast and with Mattheiu's performance tip freeing should be good too. I guess the only potential issue is the number of intervals that will be created in real-world usage with a selection of allocations and frees but that can be profiled... I have a few situations where this design might come in handy.

Comment: I have a comment on a behavior problem. Creating a variant and my unit tests discovered and issue. If you fill up the id manager and try to free the last id, you will not properly free the slot. For example, uint16_t max would be 65535, in a full IdManager, 

it = free_.upper_bound(id_interval(id,id));
    if (it == free_.end()) {
        return ;

would resolve to free_.end() since no interval can be strictly less than interval(max,max) by your operator< definition, this call to free will not modify the underlying sets. You need to check to see if the id matches the max.

Comment: When IDs are deleted there is no check to merge with previous intervals, so if you allocate n IDs then deallocate them, you get n intervals with range of 1. This wastes alot of memory!

Answer (score 1):

It would be good to know how many ids you're supposed to keep track of. If there's only a hundred or so, a simple `set` would do, with linear traversal to get a new id. If it's more like a few thousands, then of course the linear traversal will become a performance killer, especially considering the cache unfriendliness of the set.

Personally, I would go for the following:

- `set`, which helps keeping track of the ids easily `O(log N)`
- proposing the new id as the current maximum + 1... `O(1)`

If you don't allocate (in the lifetime of the application) more than `max<int>()` ids, it should be fine, otherwise... use a larger type (make it unsigned, use a `long` or `long long`) that's the easiest to begin with.

And if it does not suffice, leave me a comment and I'll edit and search for more complicated solutions. But the more complicated the book-keeping, the longer it'll take to execute in practice and the higher the chances of making a mistake.

Comment: My current implementation uses a set and linear search. Current max + 1 is a great idea although it completely fails if the user chooses INT_MAX or UINT_MAX as one of their personal ids. By fail I mean I'd have fall back to the linear search.

The thing is, this is a GL driver and glBind functions are called hundreds of times per 60hz frame. Therefore O(log N) seems too slow on lookup.

Answer (score 0):

But I don't think you have to guarantee the id must starts from 1. You can just make sure the available id must be larger than all allocated ids.

Like if the 3 is registered first, then the next available id can just be 4. I don't think it is necessary to use 1.

Comment: Except then you aren't reusing id's and you have placed a limit on the total number of id's you can ever allocate, even if your user is allocating, using and then releasing the ids.

Comment: What if the first ID registered is 0xffffffff?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to be able to use all available values for the Id type and that you want to reuse freed Ids? I'm also assuming that you'll lock the collection if you're using it from more than one thread...

I'd create a class with a set to store the allocated ids, a list to store the free ids and a max allocated value to prevent me having to preload the free id list with every available id.

So you start off with an empty set of allocated ids and empty list of free ids and the max allocated as 0. You allocate, take the head of the free list if there is one, else take max, check it's not in your set of allocated ids as it might be if someone reserved it, if it is, increment max and try again, if not add it to the set and return it.

When you free an id you simply check it's in your set and if so push it on your free list.

To reserve an id you simply check the set and if not present add it.

This recycles ids quickly, which may or may not be good for you, that is, allocate(), free(), allocate() will give you the same id back if no other threads are accessing the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Compressed vector. But I don't think any container would make noticeable difference.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, i'd say stick to an simple implementation until you have an idea of which methods are used most. Premature tuning might prove wrong. Use the simple implementation, and log its use, then you can optimize from the functions that are used the most. No use in optimizing for quick removal or quick allocation if you only need a couple of hundred ids and a simple vector would be enough.

Comment: I would say checking if an id exist has to be the fast part because glBindXXX is called hundreds or thousands of times per 60hz frame and each call has to check if the id exists or not so it knows whether or not to register a new id.

Comment: But do you have any idea of how many ids you will normally need. Could you afford an occational time consuming reallocation, or is it better to have allocation time fixed and a bit more time consuming checking. A vector gives you quick lookup, but is more fiddly when it comes to adding and removing. But if your number of id is semi fixed, it might be the correct choice anyhow, if you can afford a large reallocation in those cases when the current pool is exhausted i'd stick to an vector and use a queue to keep track of the free ids.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [skwllsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620218/fastest-container-or-algorithm-for-unique-reusable-ids-in-c/2622526#2622526), I'd keep track of the ranges that have not been allocated, but my methods are slightly different. The base container would be a map, with the key being the upper bound of the range and the value being the lower bound.

```
IdManager::IdManager()
{
    m_map.insert(std::make_pair(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), 1);
}

int IdManager::AllocateId()
{
    assert(!m_map.empty());
    MyMap::iterator p = m_map.begin();
    int id = p->second;
    ++p->second;
    if (p->second > p->first)
        m_map.erase(p);
    return id;
}

void IdManager::FreeId(int id)
{
    // I'll fill this in later
}

bool IdManager::MarkAsUsed(int id)
{
    MyMap::iterator p = m_map.lower_bound(id);

    // return false if the ID is already allocated
    if (p == m_map.end() || id < p->second || id > p->first)))
        return false;

    // first thunderstorm of the season, I'll leave this for now before the power glitches
}

bool IdManager::IsUsed(int id)
{
    MyMap::iterator p = m_map.lower_bound(id);
    return (p != m_map.end() && id >= p->second && id <= p->first);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So a friend pointed out that in this case a hash might be better. Most OpenGL programs don't use more than a few thousand ids so a hash with say 4096 slots is almost guaranteed to have only 1 or 2 entries per slot. There is some degenerate case where lots of ids might go in 1 slot but that's seriously unlikely. Using a hash would make AllocateID much slower but a set could be used for that. Allocating being slower is less important than InUse being fast for my use case.