# How assigning unique identifiers to an object that increase but remembers deletion of previous objects, in C++

Tags: c++

## 1. The Problem

I would like to have a unique ID for each object, but, with this code, the IDs increase but never decrease. How can I have a unique ID dependent on the number of the object that exists.

## 2. The Code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class UniqueID {
protected:
    static int nextID;
public:
    int id;
    UniqueID();
    ~UniqueID();
    UniqueID(const UniqueID& orig);
    UniqueID& operator=(const UniqueID& orig);
};

int UniqueID::nextID = 0;

UniqueID::UniqueID() {
    id = ++nextID;
}

UniqueID::~UniqueID() {

}

UniqueID::UniqueID(const UniqueID& orig) {
    id = orig.id;
}

UniqueID& UniqueID::operator=(const UniqueID& orig) {
    id = orig.id;
    return(*this);
}

int main()
{

    std::vector<UniqueID> UniqueIDs;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        UniqueID e;
        UniqueIDs.push_back(e);
        std::cout <<"Create "<< e.id << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    //Delete..
    for (int b = int(UniqueIDs.size()) - 1; b >= 0; b--)
    {

        std::cout << "Delete "<< UniqueIDs[b].id << std::endl;
        UniqueIDs.erase(UniqueIDs.begin() + b);
    }

    std::cout << "\n";

    //Here the new object should get the ids for 1 to 4 
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        UniqueID e;
        UniqueIDs.push_back(e);
        std::cout << "Create " << e.id << std::endl;
    }
}
```

## 3. The Output

The output is:

```
Create 1
Create 2
Create 3

Delete 3
Delete 2
Delete 1

Create 4
Create 5
Create 6
```

## 4. What I wanted

And I would like to have:

```
Create 1
Create 2
Create 3

Delete 3
Delete 2
Delete 1

Create 1
Create 2
Create 3
```

How can I remember where to start the IDs after deletion of some of them?

Comment: I don't see where you decrease the counter

Comment: Something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620218/fastest-container-or-algorithm-for-unique-reusable-ids-in-c)?

Comment: You would need to hold on to a static `vector` of ids, and remove the ones that are deleted, in the constructor, so that you can reuse them.

Comment: Why don't you use the address/index of each element as its id?

Comment: Copying the ids of existing objects makes them non-unique.

Comment: Can you really call it a unique id if some other object used to have it?

Comment: Are you afraid of running out of 64-bit integers?

Answer (score 3):

There's a reason IDs are not usually re-used like this, and that's because you'd have to either keep a collection of spare IDs, or a collection of used IDs, and that does not scale (unless you artificially constrain yourself to a small number of "slots").

Databases just auto-increment all the way to the top of the integer range, then wrap back around (you're unlikely to have 4 billion objects concurrently!). In code, it's common to just use the address of the object, which is already guaranteed to be unique and stable for its lifetime.